# UIPath truncating strings at 10k (10,000) characters

Tags: uipath, uipath-robot

We are running into an issue with UIPath that recently started. It's truncating strings, in our case a base 64 encoded image, at 10k characters. Does anyone know why this might be happening, and how we can address it?

The truncation appears to be happening when loading the text variable base64Contents. Seen in the photo below.

base64Contents = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

[image: UIPathActivity]

Answer (score 0):

As per the UiPath documentation there is a limit of 10,000 characters. This is due to `'the default communication channel between the Robot Executor and the Robot Service has changed from WCF to IPC'`

https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/log-message

#### Potential Solution

A way round this could be to write your string to a txt file rather than output it as a log. that way you are using a different activity and the 10,000 character limit may not apply.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue isn't with a log though, it is when we save the byte 64 string to a text variable, and then try to post the string to an API and only get 10k characters of the byte 64 string. The docs for Text Variable don't seem to indicate what the limit is, can you confirm that the change to IPC is also effecting this?

https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/text-variables

Comment: Can you update your question with a bit more detail around the activities you're using in your sequence? There are a few points you could check. Is the issue with UiPath eg something wrong with it getting/calculating the string, is the issue sending the string to the API? is the API receiving it and truncating it?

Comment: Great thoughts, it appears to happen on the conversion when setting a variable with Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray).

Comment: So does it just return the first 10000 characters after you've ran `Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)`? also what datatype are you storing `base64Contents` as?